# como agregarle un id a un elemento creado por medio de un createElement("tag");

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, programación-bajo-nivel

Quiero crear una lista, a la cual se le añaden nuevos elementos por medio de un `input` (eso ya lo hice). Pero ahora, quiero borrar esos elementos al darle click encima de ellos, la cosa es que no se como seleccionarlos, ya que estos no cuentan con un `id` al crearlos por medio de un `createElement("tag");`,
sólo quisiera saber como poder tomar ese elemento para eliminarlo por medio de un `removeChild()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de crear el elemento:

```
 var elemento = document.createElement("div");
```

Puedes setearle cualquier atributo como el id de la siguiente manera:

```
elemento.setAttribute("id", "idPrueba");
```

y luego le puedes setear un evento click donde te enseño como borrarlo:

```js
var elemento = document.createElement("div");
elemento.setAttribute("id", "idPrueba");

elemento.onclick = function () {
    alert("Soy un div");
    alert("Me voy a borrar")
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
};

document.body.appendChild(elemento);
```

```css
#idPrueba{
 border:1px solid red;
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
}
```

**OTRO EJEMPLO COMO TU LO QUIERES:**

```js
var newElemento = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(newElemento);
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  
  elementos[i].setAttribute("id", "idPrueba"+i);
  elementos[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Soy un div");
    alert("Me voy a borrar")
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
  });
  
}
```

```css
#idPrueba0{
 border:1px solid red;
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
}
```

Espero te ayude

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias..,yo queria hacerlo mediante un; 
 document.getElementsByTagName("li").addEventListener("click",borrar); // li es el nodo creado
function borrar(){
//codigo
}
pero aun tengo problemas con eso..
ahora probare tu metodo..

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi ejemplo con otro ejemplo como lo quieres, espero te sirva

Comment: es verdad..mi error era no hacer el bucle para agregarle el EventListener a todos..mi logica era que al declararlo una sola vez mediante un tagName..me tomara todos los <li> y solo tomaria su id para borrarlos mediante a este..pero ahora veo mi error..Gracias te debo el librarme de este dolor de cabeza que al parecer no era tan dificil..saludos y que estes bien!!

Comment: siempre a su orden, que estés bien

Answer (score 1):

Para asignar un `id` o cualquier atributo con `createElement` tenes que usar `setAttribute`, otra opción sería modificar la propiedad `id`, te dejo un ejemplo

```js
//Opción uno, usando setAttribute
ej = document.createElement('input');
ej.setAttribute("id", "Input1");

//Opción dos, usando la propiedad id
ej2 = document.createElement('input');
ej2.id = "Input2"


document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ej);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ej2);
```

```css
#Input1
{
  background-color: red;
}
#Input2
{
  background-color: cyan;
}
input{
display: block;
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Aclaro que el `css` está sólo a fines demostrativos.

Comment: entiendo...te agradesco por tomarte de tu tiempo para ayudarme...saludos!!